# Cannot reference Access subform Form object until the first row of parent form has been expanded

Tags: vba, ms-access

When the parent form is opened in datasheet view, I cannot reference the Form object of a subform control until the first row of the parent form has been expanded.

I would like to know a good workaround to this.  I need to be able to requery this kind of subform even if the first row of the parent form datasheet has not yet been expanded.

## Steps to reproduce the problem:

Create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
  PK Text PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Sub (
  PK Text PRIMARY KEY,
  FK Text REFERENCES Parent (PK)
);
```

Insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO Parent (PK) VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO Parent (PK) VALUES ('B');

INSERT INTO Sub (PK,FK) VALUES ('AA','A');
INSERT INTO Sub (PK,FK) VALUES ('BB','B');
```

Create two forms based on these tables and set the default view to `Datasheet`.
Add `Sub` form to `Parent` form and link on `sub.FK=parent.PK`.
Give the subform container control the name `child`.
Open the `Parent` form.
Expand the ***first*** row of the datasheet and then collapse it.
Attempt to requery the subform as follows:

```
Forms!Parent!child.Form.Requery  'This succeeds.
```

Close and re-open the `Parent` form.
Expand the ***second*** row of the datasheet and then collapse it.
Attempt to requery the subform again using the same code.

This time it fails with the following error:

```
Run-time error '2455':
You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report.
```

From this, I have to conclude that in datasheet view, a subform Form object is not reference-able until the first row of the parent form is expanded.

Comment: That's by design. A parent record must be present, or the child records would be orphaned - which is a definitive _no-no_.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  A parent record is present.  The problem is that the sub form cannot be re-queried unless the **first** record in the parent form datasheet has been expanded.

Comment: You should clarify that the subform is in `Detail` section not Footer/Header or you won't get an expandable `Datasheet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is correct, but it I think that this is caused by the repeated `SubForm` control. Each of them is a different `Form` Object, although they have the same name.

The difference between the first and the second record is the `Focus`. If you expand the first record, first control of `SubForm` gets focus. For the second record you have to set focus yourself. If you click on a record of the second records `Subform` the `.Requery` works. If you click on first record  after this (not expand) your `:Requery` fails too.

Another thing to try. After expanding first records subform, expand the second one (without setting focus to a control). Now add a record to table `Sub` with `B` as `FK` and then `.Requery`. You will see that second records subform is not requeried, just the first!

**Solution:** Requery the control not the form with

```
 Forms!Parent!child.Requery
```

That affects all records.

Comment: Yep, you are right.  As you said, the focus goes to the first record of the subform when the first record of the parent form is expanded.  (I did not know that -- very helpful).  If you expand the first record, then put the focus on the second (collapsed) parent record, it also fails.

Comment: I also did not know that the subform control (which I name 'child') has a `.Requery` method!  Grateful also for that.  That is really the solution to my problem.

Comment: The real difference is that each of them is an independent object and they are fully initialized when they get focus, because if you have thousands of records that would create thousands of `Form` objects. To minimze the effort they are computed seperate.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you again.